# Will the next ENSO event be of modoki type?

Tags: meteorology, climate, enso

Where can I find free information to learn if the forecasted ENSO El Nino event for 2nd semester 2017 will be a MODOKI one?

The Japan Meteo Service also publishes the EL-NINO-MODOKI Index (below), but:
 - what are the chances/probability that we are going through JULY and AUGUST under a Modoki El Niño ?

[image]

Comment: You can start here: https://www.forbes.com/sites/marshallshepherd/2017/01/17/what-experts-think-of-speculation-that-el-nino-will-return-in-2017/#6ee5a8fc791b

Comment: @aretxabaleta very good reference. There's two helpful links in the story, thanks! I also found a calculation of EMI (el-nino Modoki Index) from the Japan Meteo Service: http://www.jamstec.go.jp/frcgc/research/d1/iod/e/seasonal/outlook.html :::: would love to hear some more interpretation on it.